# Facebook Pixel Fire on Button Click

Tags: javascript, facebook

Hello I would like to install a button click event in my Facebook code:

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=
[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}
(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', 'myid'); // Insert your pixel ID here.
fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id='myid'&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- DO NOT MODIFY -->
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

My site does not have a thank-you page for tracking form fills, but it does have a submit button labeled "Get Started".

I believe the submission button on the site is defined as follows:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-grn btn-block">Get Started</button>
```

Would something like this work:

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=
[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}
(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', 'myid'); // Insert your pixel ID here.
fbq('track', 'PageView');

 var button = document.getElementById('Get Started');
 button.addEventListener(
'click', 
function() { 
  fbq('track', 'Lead', {
    content_name: 'Get Started Submissions', 
    content_category: 'Form Fill',
    value: 0.00,
    currency: 'USD' 
  });          
},
false
);


</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id='myid'&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- DO NOT MODIFY -->
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Can someone assist with tracking this button-click as a custom conversion or a complete registration Facebook event?

I understand that I can add an event listener to the pixel if I need to track clicks, but I am still very new to Javascript.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I don't know if anything else is causing a problem, but I can see at least one thing that is wrong: your button does not have an `id`, and you're doing `document.getElementById('Get Started')` which is not an id.

Comment: OK, would you recommend a different method? Maybe if I changed it to:      var button = <button type="submit" class="btn btn-grn btn-block">Get Started</button>('Get Started');

Comment: No. In your HTML, add an id to your button: `<button id="get-started-button" type="submit"....`, and then in your JS script, use that id by doing `document.getElementById('get-started-button')`

Comment: Perfect! Appreciate the help blex!